# Drawing a 2D plan with spring mvc web

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a problem with my dock management application(built with `spring MVC`). In my application I need to build a view (in 2D plan) of the available docks. So my problem is that I don't know how to build such a view (the docks have a coordinate (x, y) and a length/width). What I really want is to have a 2D plan (with x and y axes) in which I build rectangles that represent the docks.

But I don't know how to do that in my `@Controller`.

I am using JSPs to display the data.

Do you have any ideas on a possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add some code to illustrate what you are trying to do? I'd say the controller will return a list of docks to the JSP view and in the JSP you will handle the drawing logic

Comment: So the controller should only send a list of docks(on json form)? then in my jsp i should iterate over them to construct the shapes

Comment: Yeah, that's up to you, how you implement it. I would do it that way. The controller will handle only the data and the JSP will draw it depending on that data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.